# Typescript TS2339 Property doesn't exist on type - Class decleration

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, types

I am using exact example outlined in Typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#classes

This is exact copy I am running  in app.ts

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}



window.onload = () => {

    function greeter(person: Person) {
        return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
    }

    var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

    document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);

}
```

but I get following errors

```
ERROR in ./src/app.ts
(3,14): error TS2339: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Student'.

ERROR in ./src/app.ts
(4,14): error TS2339: Property 'middleInitial' does not exist on type 'Student'.

ERROR in ./src/app.ts
(5,14): error TS2339: Property 'lastName' does not exist on type 'Student'.

ERROR in ./src/app.ts
(6,14): error TS2339: Property 'fullName' does not exist on type 'Student'.
```

I am using typescript 2.4 and here the `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "scripthost",
      "dom"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "files": [
    "node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts",
    "typings/file-loader.d.ts"
    ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch",
    "node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to compile in the TypeScript playground.

Comment: My 2.41. says your code is ok. Restart your IDE :D And try class Student implements Person

Comment: Some notes, don't need the exclude and extra files entries on node_modules. Let tsc do its work. :)

Comment: @Aron yes it works on playground just not on the project... hence I am confused... I've restarted the IDE, ran clean `npm install`, removed all the other files and this is stripped down version of the code me trying to isolate why its not working...

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring some public properties of your class directly in the consctructor so you should use `"this"` keyword

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = this.firstName + " " + this.middleInitial + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Edit : [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15af1htc/)

Comment: yes but the fiddle also works when you remove the `this.`s, hence why I asked @MonteCristo to check on his IDE

Comment: so comes from webpack configuration I guess

Comment: @OrcusZ it was indeed webpack I had this rule ```rules: [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },{enforce: 'pre', test: /\.js$/, use: "source-map-loader"},{
                enforce: 'pre', test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            },
            {
                // For our normal typescript
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: {configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'}
                }],exclude: /(?:node_modules)/,},]```

Comment: I had to get rid of normal .ts extension related rule `// For our normal typescript test: /\.ts?$/, use: [{ loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: {configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'} }],exclude: /(?:node_modules)/,}`

Comment: seems to be a normal config. Did you test ?

Answer (score -4):

This seems to work fine?

```js
var Student = (function() {
  function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
  }
  return Student;
}());

function greeter(person) {
  return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

```html
<!-- TYPESCRIPT
var Student = (function () {
    function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
    return Student;
}());
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
-->
```