# Property does on exist on type when defining classes

Tags: typescript

If I have a class such as:

```js
class X {
  a: number;

  constructor (inputA: number) {
    this.a = inputA;
  }

  f () {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}

const test = new X(1);
test.f();
```

[Everything works fine in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1pgFzQHYFcC2ARgKYBOA3EitMAPZYQAuJOwDNJ0AFAJZYAOOBgEFMuQqQCUiKqgYALbhAB0YaAF5ovAcIqoAvpVQAzLlOSpUtejRBElIGgHNO8xSom7oBg0iuNoDET%20GlhEAO5wnACMHkiBjEpGnB5AA)

If I bring that into my codebase, I get the error:

> TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'X'.

I'm running this through webpack, so I'm guessing there's something wrong there - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297419/typescript-ts2339-property-doesnt-exist-on-type-class-decleration) appears to have a similar problem but there aren't any answers which are usable.

Comment: I'm 99.99999% sure there are no tsconfig properties that make something so fundamental not work. There must be some other problem -- perhaps you have old code somewhere that isn't being recompiled, or a typo that isn't replicated above, or something. That is very basic TypeScript code, so the problem isn't in that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, that's good to know - looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297419/typescript-ts2339-property-doesnt-exist-on-type-class-decleration) it seems like it may be a webpack issue, but it's a little hard to make sense of the answers on that question